# Overriding repo file when installing composer dependencies in Laravel

Tags: php, git, bash, laravel, automation

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I have the following workflow issue:

For the login of the app I am developing, I customized the trait `AuthenticatesUsers` under `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` that comes out-of-the-box with Laravel with my custom `login()` method.

The changes are being tracked by git. The issue comes when I commit, push and then pull the changes when logged into my server.

My problem is the following. The `AuthenticatesUsers.php` file gets overridden when I do a `composer update --no-dev` (since I am in my staging server) with the default package's file, throwing away all the customizations I made to the `login()` method.

I wanted to try to automate the process of overriding the file by possibly creating a "postUpdate" composer script. Or maybe go with a bash script? I am tired of overriding the file manually with git after every time I update my composer dependencies.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: What kind of customizations do you need for the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait? Laravel provides a bunch of config options, and at worst case you should be able to move your custom implementation out of the `vendor` folder to avoid conflicts. [See the docs.](//laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

Comment: You are right. I am going to refactor my code/structure and move the logic out of vendor, but as a short-term solution I need to be able to do this. I am re-defining the login method because a valid login in my app does not come from the DB but rather from an API call to another system

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Is your `vendor` folder tracked by Git, or is it ignored? What about your `composer.lock`?

Comment: It is being tracked. I think I just solved it though. I just didn't update the components, and then it doesn't override my file. It kind of prevents me from updating my dependencies from my remote server, but it is ok since I can deal with it locally and then push & pull again. I will have to refactor my code later so I amend this unfortunate dev process. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your AuthController uses AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, but that doesn't mean you can't override the methods in your controller, or alternatively use your own AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers (copy) version of the file.

You don't want to modify anything in the vendor directory (including Illuminate). These are vendor packages. There's a reason why composer overwrites vendor packages; it's not your code to modify and it allows the package maintainer to provide you with updates like security fixes and bugfixes. Overwriting a file in a vendor package may break due to other changes to dependencies within the package in other files.

So instead of modifying a vendor package, extend the class and/or override the method(s). You can look at AuthenticatesUsers and copy the method, postLogin, into your controller, for example:

```
AuthController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

        if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        }

        if ($throttles) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        // Overriding the postLogin to deliver 401 unauthorized instead of redirecting back to login with errors
        abort(401, "Oh no you don't");

        // return redirect($this->loginPath())
        //     ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        //     ->withErrors([
        //         $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        //     ]);
    }

}
```